# How to get like result of SQl in combobox auto complete mode

Tags: c#, sql, .net, combobox, autocomplete

I am using combo box with code below

```
comboBoxPartCondition.SelectedIndex = 0;
comboBoxPartNo.DataSource = data.Tables[0];
comboBoxPartNo.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
comboBoxPartNo.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
comboBoxPartNo.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBoxPartNo.ValueMember = "Id";
```

It works fine as Expected when i type b[image]. But when i type 11 it doesn't show any suggestion. I want it to work like " like in sql %ÇHAR%". How can i achieve this.

Comment: you have to overwrite that function by your own try this
[codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16285/Auto-Complete-ComboBox)

Comment: above suggested link work on first character only.